# MySQL: for each row on table then get data from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem in MySQL. It involves two tables, now the first table queries the **TrackingNo** then other table queries the details based on the **TrackingNo**. *(See sample image below)*

**>> Table1**

[image]

**>> Table2**

[image]

As you can see the images above, **Table1** returns `77 records` then those 77 records has details on **Table2**.For example, **TrackNo.** `xxx000001` must get the newest **date/time** which is `2015-03-09 17:53:14` and same on the other TrackNo.

My problem is what query should I use? I think, this problem works great on SQL Server using `WITH CTE` but I made some research that `WITH Clause` is not supported in **MySQL**.

**>> Desired output:**

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
|  TrackNo  |  Status  |      Date/Time      |
+===========+==========+=====================+
| xxx000001 | Logged   | 2015-03-09 17:53:14 |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| xxx000002 | Prepped  | 2014-08-15 17:19:00 |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
| xxx000003 | Analyzed | 2014-10-10 11:12:00 |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Any suggestions and alternatives is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your desired output  filed `track no` different from `table1` and `table2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   t2.TrackNo, 
   t2.Status, 
   MAX(t2.DateTime) 
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 
WHERE t1.TrackNo = t2.TrackNo 
GROUP BY t2.TrackNo
```

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL we have powerful operations called JOINS.
You can use JOIN to get the output from the two tables based on the column that is same on both tables.

For example:

```
   SELECT 
   table2.TrackNo, table2.Status, MAX(table2.DateTime) 
FROM Table1 table1, Table2 table2
WHERE table1.TrackNo = table2.TrackNo 
GROUP BY table2.TrackNo;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `TrackingNo` as t1 where t1.date=(select max(t2.date) from TrackingNo as t2 where t1.trackNo=t2.trackNo)